# SUM the quantity and Displaying in column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What i want is, when i add amount in "ADD QUANTITY" it will add that quantity in quantity column and shows the updated quantity in quantity text area. eg if i add 25 in add quantity it display 50 in QUANTITY.

VIEW contain Product id,Name, ,Quantity,Price, Add quantity, Update button

and table contains:
`p_id,p_name,p_quantity,p_price`

What will be the query? as i am using

```
SELECT SUM(p_quantity)
FROM
  (SELECT sum(ADD quantity) AS Quantity
   FROM main_inventory
   WHERE name='p_quantity')a
```

but it is not displaying any good result..

Thanks in advance for responce.

Comment: Can you please show your table with some sample data and your expected output in a tabular format?

Comment: p_id  |  p_name  |  p_quantity |  p_price  |                          1     |  butter  |  25         |  200      |                           2     |Cream     | 300         |  250      |                        what i want is when i add quantity in another textbar of same  view it will add it in quantity colum as 25+25 =50                         my view contain                                                       id|Product name|product quantity|price|add new quantity| submit button

Comment: so when you perform update, it will never affect your database but only font end display?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(p_quantity + quantity) as quantity 
FROM main_inventory 
WHERE name='p_quantity'
```

Where quantity being set as valid number by php codes.

eg:

```
    SELECT SUM(p_quantity + 25) as quantity 
    FROM main_inventory 
    WHERE name='p_quantity'
```

Comment: it is static value which always add 25, i want different values according to users requirement.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you want is to display the quantity number to your application before update, query below can do it, however, use programming to handle will be better

```
DECLARE @SAMPLE TABLE
(
p_id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
p_NAME NVARCHAR(255),
p_Quantity INT,
p_Price INT
)

INSERT INTO @SAMPLE VALUES ('butter',25,200)
INSERT INTO @SAMPLE VALUES ('Cream',300,250)

--YOUR DATABASE ITEM(s)
SELECT * FROM @SAMPLE

--DECLARE USER INPUT(S)
DECLARE @AddQuantity INT

--PLAY AROUND YOUR QUANTITY HERE
SET @AddQuantity = 25

SELECT p_Quantity + @AddQuantity 'Front End Display Output', p_Quantity 
'Value in database' FROM @SAMPLE
```